# Missing values in truncate data frame

Tags: r

I have the next dataframe (t) with 317,000 obs.

```
date | page | rank
2015-10-10 | url1 | 1
2015-10-10 | url2 | 2
2015-10-10 | url2 | 3
.
.
.
2015-10-10 | url1000 | 1000
2015-10-11 | url1 | 1
```

I'm trying to truncate this data, because I want to know how much days, a particular URL have maintained in the rank 50 or less.

```
piv = reshape(t,direction = "wide", idvar = "page", timevar = "date")
```

If I do that I obtained a table with 27,447 obs and 318 columns, but it generates a lot of NAs. Example below (only 20 columns)

```
    page id.2015-12-07 id.2015-12-08 id.2015-12-09 id.2015-12-10 id.2015-12-11 id.2015-12-12 id.2015-12-13
1 url1             1             1             1             1             1             2             2
  id.2015-12-14 id.2015-12-15 id.2015-12-16 id.2015-12-17 id.2015-12-18 id.2015-12-19 id.2015-12-20 id.2015-12-21
1             1             1             1             1           106           534            NA           282
  id.2015-12-22 id.2015-12-23 id.2015-12-24 id.2015-12-26
1           270           445            NA            NA
```

Also using cast I had the next error

```
pivoted = cast(t,page ~ rank + date )

****Using id as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , variables, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected****
```

I have 317 uniques dates and 27,447 unique pages or urls.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the `dplyr` package for this kind of tasks, if this is possible for you:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 filter(rank <= 50) %>% 
 group_by(page) %>%
 summarize(days_in_top_50 = n())
```

will give you the result you are looking for.

You have row per page and day. The first line (`filter`) means you only want to consider rows where the rank was in the top 50. The second line (`group_by`) means you want to get results by page and finally in the third line the `n()` function counts those rows that pass the filter for each page.

For more information you can check out https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: I will look the documentation. Quick question, instead of df I'm using t (the dataframe commented), and r session collapses. It's that expectable?

Comment: If your dataframe is named `t`. then you should use `t` instead of df. This shouldn't cause any errors.
You might have to install the `dplyr` package before using it for the first time: `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: perfect. Yes it is installed, but r session collapses for some reason.

Comment: You don't get any error messages, but instead the entire session crashes/freezes? Maybe the data frame is too big for the local memory?

Comment: @AngeloCanepa `t` is the matrix transpose function. It's not a good idea to call your dataframe the same name as a base `R` function. Name your dataframe something else that isn't already a function name, and then try it again.